# Specify a filelist to run script build phase in Xcode

Tags: xcode

In my project I need to generate a cpp file from the specific project cpp files and include it to "Compile Sources" build phase. I have a python script to generate it. But how can I specify the list of that files to "Run Script" build phase which executes that script (the script takes the names of files as arguments)?

PS

The list of this files is a list of cpp files which I compile. XCode 3.2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about Xcode3, but Xcode4 seems to create a file called foo.LinkFileList (for a target named foo), in the DerivedFiles hierarchy.  Xcode is even nice enough to make an environment variable that points to this file, called ${FILE_LIST}.  You can tell for sure if you simply call "env" at the top of your script - that'll display all the environment variables, and you can cross-ref those against your known file locations.